# What are possible causes of appmenu-gtk failing to connect to D-Bus?

Tags: permissions, firefox, dbus, apparmor

The warning is

> ** (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:1671): WARNING **: 22:14:54.614: Unable to connect to dbus: Could not connect: Permission denied

I tried using strace but can't find any related file errors there. <s>I guess it could be AppArmor.</s> Any suggestion on how to find the cause?

<s>I started to search because no matter Visual bell setting is set to (`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell false`) Firefox flashes whole window to inverse colors when search on page did not return any results and it's annoying.</s> **This was fixed by changing KDE settings.**

- libappmenu-gtk*-parser0 0.7.1-1
- Firefox 65.0 (both installed through apt and downloaded)
- D-Bus 1.12.12-1ubuntu1
- Ubuntu 19.04

I had ~/.dbus/ owned by root somehow, but tried changing owner to my user recursively and deleting the folder. Both times nothing changed even after a complete reboot.

I would've reported it as bug but want to make sure it really is one.

#### Update

It's not Firefox, it's `appmenu-gtk*`:

```
$ grep "Unable to connect to dbus" -rF /usr
Binary file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libappmenu-gtk-module.so matches
Binary file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libappmenu-gtk-module.so matches
```

And after removing the warning changed to

> Gtk-Message: 16:30:03.964: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module".

Comment: Try running it via `strace -f -o firefox.trace  firefox https://askubuntu.com` and maybe provide the output here or on paste.ubuntu.com  It should reveal exact errors.  `~/.dbus` could be one possible issue, as EACCESS error  results from any component of pathname having restricted permissions, but since you've tried dealing with the directory something else is the culprit

Comment: Thanks! The only filename appearing with EACCES is `/usr/lib/firefox/fonts/.uuid.TMP-PtRd2i` and it looks unrelated. I'll combine stderr with strace output, will it provide a better picture? Tried it but didn't find anything.

Comment: You don't have to combine anything. `strace` writes everything to stderr or file specified by `-o` flag so everything will be there once you run the command.

Comment: I meant `strace -f firefox 2>&1 | tee firefox.trace` to include the error in question in the file, here is the result: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NxgMmvmRxz/

Comment: Alright. I'm gonna have to come back, since I'm low on battery in my laptop.  I'll dig through the paste and let you know if I figure out anything

Comment: It's not Firefox, it's `appmenu-gtk*`. Found them with `grep "Unable to connect to dbus" -rF /usr`. Warning changed after I removed these packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the output of `strace` [linked in the comments](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NxgMmvmRxz/) , here's what I found:

```
[pid  4245] sendto(35, "AUTH\r\n", 6, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 6
[pid  4245] recvfrom(35, "REJECTED EXTERNAL\r\n", 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 19
[pid  4245] sendto(35, "AUTH EXTERNAL 31303031\r\n", 24, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 24
[pid  4245] recvfrom(35, "OK f9c00ca7570590f878c4db8c5c686"..., 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 37
```

What this means is that firefox ( client ) is connected to D-Bus (server) socket which is referenced by file descriptor number 35, which you can see earlier in the `strace` output:

```
[pid  4245] connect(35, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/user/1001/bus"}, 110) = 0
```

and initiates negotiation via standard commands described in [D-Bus documentation](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#auth-command-rejected). According to the documentation:

> If an AUTH command has no arguments, it is a request to list available mechanisms. The server must respond with a REJECTED command listing the mechanisms it understands, or with an error.

`REJECTED EXTERNAL` response indicates response that the bus accepts EXTERNAL method of authentication. So the warning message likely came from the initial exchange.  However, it later succeeds with the `AUTH EXTERNAL` method.

Thus, the conclusion I draw from this is that

1. this is not a firefox bug, though might be a false positive
2. the fact that it is just a warning makes it somewhat insignificant issue, considering that you still can use firefox.

Additionally, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libappmenu-gtk-module.so` is a shared object which is meant to be used by multiple applications and it is not specific to firefox. Removing it may hide the warning, but it's probably not the best idea since this is a shared object and other applications may rely on it for proper working.

You can still submit a bug report with link to this answer to firefox developers as warning appears after initial negotiation method, whereas firefox probably could try other methods first before issuing the warning, however I wouldn't count on this being high-priority issue for the developers and likely it will be left with WONTFIX status.